# Porting large HTML hymnal with .mid audio samples to Android

Tags: android, html, webview, midi

LTLFTC..

My mother gave me a project to do for her church. It's an HTML hymnal with over 1300 songs worth of lyrics, and she would like it converted to an Android app. Each song has its own .htm and there's some basic css. There's also a .mid for most songs.

I've never written anything for Android. As far as I can tell, the .htm should work fine in webview, but I want to allow the user to push a button to play the associated .mid file for each song. I also want to distribute the whole mess as an .apk so non-techies can pretty easily install it.

I figure I can put the .mid files in /res/raw, and I guess I'll need to use jetplayer to actually play them back. Not sure how.

I also figure I can just use webview to show the lyrics of each one.

What I'm foggy on is this: How do I call/name 1300+ html files from an Android app without having to manually edit each one? If I include them in /res/raw, can they still be called by name (0001.htm, 0002.htm, etc.) and is that even a good idea?

I don't mind editing them all by hand, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Sorry if this is too nooby, and thanks for any advice.

edit: Got the html, css, and most of the js working. Is it possible to call MediaPlayer from within my html or js? Under Windows, there is both an embedded player, and a simple link to the .mid file within each hymn.html. The embedded player is defined in a.js, and looks like this:

```
// Embed the music player into the webpage.
function embed_music(filename)
{
  var type="mid";
  var width=280;
  var height=44;
  //document.write('<embed src="'+filename+'" if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {  type="application/x-mplayer2" }if 

(navigator.appName=="Netscape") {  type="audio/'+type+'" }pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" width="144" height="44" 

autostart="true" loop="true" border="1">')
  if(filename=="none")
    document.write("<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style=\"width:"+width+"px;height:"+height+"px;border:1px solid #dddddd;\"><tr><td 

style=text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;font-size:80%;>The music file for this hymn is unavailable! Sorry!</td></tr></table>")
  else
    document.write('<embed src="'+filename+'" type=audio/'+type+' autostart=false loop=false width='+width+' height='+height+'>')
}
```

And inside the individual hymn html files are stuff like this:

```
<script>embed_music("../../midi/e0011.mid")</script>
```

Ideally I'd be able to just change a.js and leave each individual .html alone, but if I need to edit them all, I will.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html and css files might be better in the `assets` folder than in raw. That way, they're going to be compressed before packaging. Files placed in `raw` will not be compressed.

You can list the contents of `assets` very simply --

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
String[] assetList = am.list( "" );
for( String asset : assetList ) {
    if( asset.endsWith( ".htm" ) ) {
        // do something with the html file
    }
}
```

Also, Android's `MediaPlayer` supports midi playback:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
File f = new File( ... path to midi ... );
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
FileDescriptor fd = fis.getFD();
mp.setDataSource( fd );
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```